# TortoiseGit - how to tell what files have changed on remote (origin) server?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

How can you tell which files have changed remotely (on the origin server)?

I thought if you did a "Fetch" that the client would learn which files have changed and so be able to show you in a list or - more intuitively given the interface - as overlay icons on those files. But I can't figure out what it's actually doing. And then what about the "Sync" and "Check for Modifications" commands - what are they for if not to show you what has changed beyond your local computer?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to see what changed on the remote.

First, when you do a normal fetch only the local remote tracking branches are updated and not you local branch you are working on. After the fetch you can open the log an compare your local branch to the now updated remote tracking branch.

Maybe a bit more easy:
Second, you can use the [Sync dialog](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-sync.html). After a successful fetch, there is the new tab "Ref list". There you can see what remote tracking branches have changed (e.g. changetype fast forward). Then you can open the context menu on an entry a request a diff.

Third, when you are on the branch and you also want to directly integrate the changes, just pull the remote branch. After the pull, you can see the changes by selecting "Pulled logs" and "Pulled diff" on the menu on the lower left.

Fourth, you can also use the [RefLog](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-reflog.html) to compare two states of the local remote tracking branch.

Changes to the overlay icons do not make sense, as these only reflect the status of the files regarding the HEAD/current branch.